# How to pass in a list of Strings to an Apex Action in new Flow Builder?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, visual-flows, invocable-method

I have a simple screen flow, which takes in a case Cancel Reason, and if that reason is Other, will get allow a user to specify the other reason via text entry.

We have an Apex server method called `CancelCaseInvocable`, which calls common case cancelation logic shared by other code.

I can see the Apex `@InvocableMethod` and it provides a place to specify the input and output values. The actual server method takes a `List<String>` and returns the same.

I have created a local flow variable called `Args`, which is a text collection variable. I have added the necessary args to the variable but when I try to select the variable in the `Cancel Case` Apex Action, I do not see the `Args` variable.

[image]

Here you can see that I create a `test` non-collection Text variable, which is visible, but the `Args` collection Text variable is not:

[image]

How do I pass a `List<String>` into the Apex Action when I cannot select a collection variable as an input argument?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) interface is bulkified. This allows you to map flows within Process Builder in a bulkified manner. As the documentation states, your parameter must be...

> A list of a primitive data type or a list of lists of a primitive data type – the generic Object type is not supported.

This means that to pass in a collection, you actually need to use `List<List<String>>` (or whichever other type you need), and to pass in a normal variable, you need to use `List<String>`.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you as always.